# Multiple criteria in switch - case part [PHP]

Tags: php

How can I do this?

```
switch("4"){

             case ("0" || "2") : echo "bingo"; break;
             case ("1" || "4") : echo "miss" ; break;                      
}
```

I have same code for case 0 and 2 that should be executed.

So is there way to do it with switch or I should replace them with IFs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
switch("4"){
    case "0":
    case "2":  echo "bingo"; break;
    case "1":
    case "4":  echo "miss" ; break;
}
```

The case statements execute till they encounter `break`.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch($var){

    case "0":
    case "2":
      // Do this on 0 or 2
    break;

    case "1":
    case "4":
      // Do this on 1 or 4
    break;
}
```

You can also find the switch documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)